# Updating routes in asp.net web forms using register routes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am working in an asp.net web form application. I have implemented URL routing in it using RegisterRoutes like this:

```
  void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);       
    } 


  void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
           int language = 2;
            routes.MapPageRoute("City1Route", "vacancies/" + HRTabs.GetCityTabLink(1, language), "~/City1.aspx");
            routes.MapPageRoute("City2Route", "vacancies/" + HRTabs.GetCityTabLink(2, language), "~/City2.aspx");
            routes.MapPageRoute("City3Route", "vacancies/" + HRTabs.GetCityTabLink(3, language), "~/City3.aspx");
            routes.MapPageRoute("City4Route", "vacancies/" + HRTabs.GetCityTabLink(4, language), "~/City4.aspx");
            routes.MapPageRoute("default", "vacancies/{language}", "~/City1.aspx");
        }
```

I am creating mapping using values in database.

In this application. I am updating the table ( routes). I want that these changes are depicted automatically as soon as save function is done but as Registerroutes is in application start function, it is not happening.

If I try to call   RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);     on Save button click, I get error that Route is already registered.

Please suggest me a solution to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the route table before registering your updated routes. Eg:

```
void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        int language = 2;
        routes.Clear();
        routes.MapPageRoute("City1Route", "vacancies/" + HRTabs.GetCityTabLink(1, language), "~/City1.aspx");
        routes.MapPageRoute("City2Route", "vacancies/" + HRTabs.GetCityTabLink(2, language), "~/City2.aspx");
        routes.MapPageRoute("City3Route", "vacancies/" + HRTabs.GetCityTabLink(3, language), "~/City3.aspx");
        routes.MapPageRoute("City4Route", "vacancies/" + HRTabs.GetCityTabLink(4, language), "~/City4.aspx");
        routes.MapPageRoute("default", "vacancies/{language}", "~/City1.aspx");
    }
```

Comment: It doesnt give error now when i register the routes again but links routes are not being updated. the new url doesnt show the pahe where as old url ( used in application start's register routes) shows

Comment: So if I understand, you have a page that displays a set of links, whose urls are derived from the route table. Does the application render the links after you update the route table? Might be helpful if you described your app in a bit more detail and/or give a code sample showing how the links are defined and rendered

Comment: yes @Paul, I have a table where i have saved the routes like vacancies/city1, vacancies/city 2. both links and registerroutes use this table to get/set routes url. registered routes used in app_start set the urls but when i edit that table values, clear the routes and register them again, they get updated in db and links point to new values but routes collection has old route values.